# Laravel 6: FatalThrowableError: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in TransportManager.php

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle, mailgun, laravel-6

I just updated my application to Laravel 6.

I'm sending email via Mailgun, and in my local environment I've confirmed that everything works perfectly.

But in staging I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /my/directory/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php:193
```

I've run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` and triple-checked that it is in the `vendor` folder and the `autoload` files on my staging server.

My emails are sent over a queue. I called Guzzle from a controller method and it was found without problems, but for some reason when the queue job runs, the TransportManager can't access it.

Again, in my local homestead environment emails are sent via mailgun with no errors.

I've done `artisan cache:clear` and `artisan config:clear`.

I can't think of anything else to try. Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out... Laravel queues use some code-caching magic I wasn't aware of. So my queue was using old code from before I ran `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`.

To solve the problem I had to run **`php artisan queue:restart`**.

Then I waited for my scheduler to rerun `php artisan queue:work` and my email is now sent as expected.